# How to change CK editor link option just like tinyMCE in Umbraco?

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor, tinymce, umbraco, umbraco7

I am new to umbraco.
In umbraco if you use link button it will show you option to select choose file within the site so it will work as internal link. please refer the following image. You can see on panel on right it shows file explorer. 
[image: Tiny mce]

On CK editor it doesn't show file explorer. Please check the following image. 
Is there any way that I can add file explorer on ck editor on Umbraco. 
[image: ck editor]

p.s. I am using Umbraco 7.3

Comment: Why are you using CK Editor inside Umbraco? The Umbraco tinyMCE has lots of specific modifications that I think would take a lot of effort to replicate in other RTEs (like CK) :-/

Answer (score 0):

The version of TinyMCE used in Umbraco has a load of customisations to make the image picker and link picker integrate with Umbraco. You could look at the source code for Umbraco and try and replicate the same customisations in CK Editor, but to be honest, why not just use the built in Tiny MCE Editor?

It would probably be a fairly large job to integrate CK Editor into Umbraco in the same way that TinyMCE is.